# Blocked by CORS policy is not solving! Laravel + Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://phplaravel-421708-1325291.cloudwaysapps.com/api/data/testimonials'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I am using Laravel and Vuejs.

Getting the above ERROR!!

I have installed this package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors#laravel

I have done before "Creating your own CORS profile"

In bootstrap/app.php

I added

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
```

But Still Problem has.... What I have to do now?

Also created `middleware`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
}
```

Registered that in `Kernel.php` . But nothing is working for me!!

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are registering your middleware in `$middlewareGroups` in `Kernel`

then try adding those to your middleware

```
$headers = [
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
 ];

if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
    return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
}

$response = $next($request);

foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
    $response->header($key, $value);
}

return $response;
```